# SQL - how to make a query account for all potential IDs

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are 10 possible construction sites that I need to account for in my report. However, as my code is now, when a construction site is not in my database, it isn't accounted for at all, which makes sense, but I would prefer it list all of the possible construction sites and put 0 as the value instead of returning nothing. The reason I need to do this is because I am creating reports based off these queries, and it's hard to line everything up unless I consistently have all of the construction sites accounted for every time. Here is the SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Main.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT 'Total IDs' AS [Construction site   >>>]
FROM Research INNER JOIN Main ON Research.Primary_ID = Main.ID
GROUP BY 'Total IDs'
PIVOT Research.Construction_site;
```

By the way, I am using MS Access 2007 is that makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using MS Access, why then did you specify `mysql` in the tags? Was that accidental?

Comment: No, I just thought someone who knew mysql might know how to do this, but I removed the tag.

Comment: Which table lists all the construction sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want all fields from the `Research` table, regardless of whether they are in the `Main` table. In which case, you just need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Main.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT 'Total IDs' AS [Construction site   >>>]
FROM Research LEFT OUTER JOIN Main ON Research.Primary_ID = Main.ID
GROUP BY 'Total IDs'
PIVOT Research.Construction_site;
```

This will return all rows from the `Research` table at least once - and **multiple times** if they exist more than once in the `Main` table.

Comment: Jet/ACE's SQL dialect ignores the OUTER in LEFT OUTER JOIN, and treats that identically to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Good to know, I didn't realise that. So I guess the above is still correct, but can be just LEFT JOIN instead. Thanks for the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to replace INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN. (I.e. simply change 'INNER' to 'LEFT'.) That way the construction sites not represented in Main won't be filtered out.

Comment: This isn't working, does INNER JOIN read the potential values from the Lookup in the Research table? Basically how I have it now is all of the potential values are in the lookup, but when I edit the code, it's still showing only the construction sites that have a value. EDIT: the look up is in the research table

Comment: INNER JOIN results in the rows from both sides that match each other. LEFT JOIN returns all the rows that INNER JOIN returns plus those from the left side (Research) that don't have matches in the right table (Main). For such rows, the corresponding columns in the right table have NULLs.

Comment: That said, I don't really understand why LEFT JOIN didn't work for you. Maybe using it with pivoting has its own peculiarities, not sure. (I've never done pivoting in Access.)